# Best Weapons For The Destroyer. Finished

Tags: terraria-mobile

Alright, I almost have an ankh shield, Turtle helmet/pants, (Somehow clorophyte spawned before I beated and hardmode boss) Frost chestplate, Clorophyte Claymore, Golden Shower, Water Bolt, Clockwork Assault Rifle, and 2 light discs... Yet, I still almost immediately die to the Destroyer, anybody know some better weapons or armor I could get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get full turtle. Armors are mostly useless it they're not full. Clockwork is probably enough, though Golden Shower is probably better IMHO.

Make sure you are in an open space, because Destroyer moves fairly quickly, and he is hard to get at if you are enclosed.

It's also good to have a piercing item (example-Adamantite lance).

Comment: Okay, So, I spawned him on surface, then went up to a sky bridge, and just shot down rapidly, because he wouldn't go up to the sky bridge, now I have a megashark, full turtle, rainbow staff (Beat the other 2), and almost an optic staff.

Comment: Spawn him on sky bridge. Optic staff doesn't do much for bosses (like, 30 dmg).

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot to recommend for this:

|Armor|

I would highly recommend at least Adamantite or Titanium armor (But DONT do frost armor, as the Destroyer is immune to frostburn).

|Weapons|

-I would either use a Clockwork Assault Rifle with Party bullets, or a Minishark with Meteor bullets. A Deadlus Strombow would also be a good weapon. For magic, a Nimbus Rod is very effective against the destroyer.